# Using @SuppressWarnings("unused") annotation on declaration section

Tags: java

I have a basic question relating to the `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` annotation. Basically, I would like to suppress unused warnings on a block of code in my declarations section of my class. I would prefer not to suppress unused warnings on the entire class.

Currently, I am doing this:

```
public class MyClass {
    //Constants
    private final String ACCEPT = "Yes";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final String DENY = "No";            //Not currently used
    private final String TENTATIVE = "Maybe";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final String POSTPONE = "Later";     //Not currently used

    //Variables
    private int counter;
    ....
```

I find the above code to be a bit messy with the annotations thrown in randomly like that. What I would like to do is something like:

```
//Constants
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
{
  private final String ACCEPT = "Yes";
  private final String DENY = "No";            //Not currently used
  private final String TENTATIVE = "Maybe";
  private final String POSTPONE = "Later";     //Not currently used
}

//Variables
private int counter;
....
```

This is, of course, illegal in Java as a block cannot be simply made like this. Its not a huge deal or anything, but I am curious if I am missing an obvious and elegant solution.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not making them `static`?

Comment: Good point Betoverse. I could make them static. I just threw this together as an example. However, my compiler will still throw warnings at unused static fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you reeeeealy want to keep all those unused constants, a quick and dirty trick would be;

```
public class MyClass {
//Variables
    private int counter;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final class UnusedConstants{
        private final String ACCEPT = "Yes";
        private final String DENY = "No";            
        private final String TENTATIVE = "Maybe";
        private final String POSTPONE = "Later";     
   }
}
```

And i would make them static too, but your call.

**EDIT**:
Or, what i think is much nicer:

```
public class MyClass {

    private enum Answer {

        ACCEPT ("Yes"),
        DENY ("No"),
        TENTATIVE("Maybe"),
        POSTPONE("Later");

        private final String answer;

        private Answer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return answer;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you don't get the unused warning as long as you use at least one of the values.

Comment: I think this is about as close as what I would be looking for. The reason for inserting unused constants is for readability and the fact that they will be used in the far future. I'm not sure if this improves readability, but it tells me perhaps I should relocate my constants into a dedicated constants class. That may be the best design decision. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I like that solution. Cleaner for sure.